# matplotlib multiple lines on one chart don't get how to do it?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can see how to do it using the example from Matplotlib site BUT that's only for 3 lines, what happens if you have 100? I can't figure out the way to do it with a python loop. So the layout would be

```
3/3/15 aa 10
3/4/15 aa 20
3/5/15 aa 30
3/3/15 bb 11
3/4/15 bb 21
3/5/15 bb 31
... 100 more of same 
3/3/15 cc 101
3/4/15 cc 102
3/5/15 cc 103
```

Here's the code from Matplotlib site but I don't really see how to loop over my data set.

```
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x) + x + np.random.randn(50))
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x) + 0.5 * x + np.random.randn(50))
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x) + 2 * x + np.random.randn(50))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`plt.plot()` works by entering an x and a y value. Assuming the 'aa', 'bb', 'cc' values are your y values in a list, you can do something like:

```
for yval in list1:
    plt.plot(x, yval)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey Jeff  I spotted that my data was screwed up and had to change it. Sorry about that.  My data is date ( x axis) 10 ( y axis) and AA is an example of a label I am going to apply to the line. SO I need to plot the AA line ( changing it's color, tick marker and other attributes) THEN carry on to the next BB and do the same all the way down to the 100th line. I "thought" I tried the way you offered and it didn't work because I need to change the color of the line when the AA goes to BB and so on. I really am not seeing how matplotlib does this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like what you've included in the question, you will first need to separate it into list or arrays to be plotted. Once you have done that, a sample code like this should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

time = np.arange(0,500)
aa = np.random.randn(500)
bb = np.random.randn(500)
cc = np.random.randn(500)
data = [aa,bb,cc]

plt.figure()
for y in data:
    plt.plot(time,y)

plt.show()
```

[Sample plot results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZUwq.png)

Comment: sorry no that won't work.  The co ord are x axis = date and y axis is the number. the letters are the label. so the first line would be 3/3/15 10
3/4/15 20 3/5/15 30  labelled "aa" then another line 3/3/15  11 3/4/15 21
3/5/15  31 labelled "bb" and so on.